# Laravel 5 + Prestashop 1.6? Is it possible to integrate the two?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I realise Prestashop isnt an MVC platform, and Laravel is, but i am curious if this sort of thing is possible, and how one would go about doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a Laravel application based on the database used by the Prestashop. So, both referring to the same database

Comment: But PrestaShop uses MVC ( Model -> View -> controller) pattern for software architecture.

Comment: @elPresta prestashop isn't MVC though. Their model is based on MVC, but they've called it '3 Tier Architecture'.

Comment: Okey sorry. Try to check dh24 Opcache stats module. He using Symphony on his module. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @elPresta okay thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a prestashop module using the [illuminate/db](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database) package is a way to obtain such integration. Inside your custom module folder you can use `composer require` to install the illuminate/database package (it will install the package in `vendor` subfolder). Then, following the instructions of the package itself, you can write a php file (call it `initilluminate.php`) that initializes the capsule manager:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 
// You can reuse your laravel model if you need them
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/models/MyLaravelModel.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

function initCapsule() {
  $capsule = new Capsule;
  $capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => _DB_SERVER_,
    'database' => _DB_NAME_,
    'username' => _DB_USER_,
    'password' => _DB_PASSWD_,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => 'ps_',
  ]);

  // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods
  $capsule->setAsGlobal();

  // Setup the Eloquent ORM
  $capsule->bootEloquent();
}
```

In module's main php file you will need

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/initilluminate.php';
```

And, in constructor, just call:

```
initCapsule();
```

to init the library. Then you can use your laravel models or access the db through `Capsule::table(<table_name>)->where...` using the usual laravel syntax.